# zeros disappear using str_c()

Tags: r, string, stringr

I got a problem which I just don't understand.

I would like to put together strings, depending on the number of characters:

the vector `c("1", "23", "302", "2004")` should be transformed into `c("1900001", "1900023", "1900302", "1902004")`.

Therefore I used this code:

```
test <- c("1", "23", "302", "2004")
fun_function <- function(test){

  if(nchar(test == 4)){
    str_c("190",test, sep="")
  } else {
    if(nchar(test == 3)){
      str_c("1900", test, sep="")
    } else{
      if(nchar(test == 2)){
        str_c("19000", test, sep="")
      } else{
        if(nchar(test == 1)){
          str_c("190000", test, sep="")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

res <- map(test, 
    ~fun_function(.x)) %>% 
  unlist()
```

However, instead of getting `c("1900001", "1900023", "1900302", "1902004")` I get `c("1901", "19023", "190302", "1902004")`.

Now, why I get that vector? If I'm using this function for a single case, it works:

```
nchar("1") == 1
str_c("190000", "1", sep="")
```

So, where is the problem? I just don't understand the reason for my outcome. Can someone help me with this? I also tried a For Loop using the same logic, but that does not work either.

Comment: `nchar(test == num)` should be `nchar(test) == num` in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're condition checking in the if statements is wrong. Its `nchar(test) == 4`, not `nchar(test == 4)`

But the `str_pad` function from `stringr` is a much more concise way to approach the problem. First I pad with zeros to 5 digits, and then paste a '19' onto each.

```
test2 <- str_pad(test, 5, 'left', pad = '0')
test3 <- paste0('19', test2)
test3
[1] "1900001" "1900023" "1900302" "1902004"
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're right. Okay, that was a really bad mistake by myself. 

And many thanks for your tip!

Comment: Also, interestingly `if(nchar(test ==4))` returns `TRUE` with a warning that it return an object with length > 1, explaining why OP was always getting the 190 prefix.